# Оператор ! и метод equals в Java

Tags: java, if, условия, equals

объясните пожалуйста условия нижеприведенного цикла простыми словами ?

```
if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(targName)) {
                do somtihg ...}
```

ранее в коде обявлены две String переменных: name и targName

Если переменная name не равна, равна переменной targName без учета больших букв ?  Не name равно targName ? Как это можно понять ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

оператор `!` просто переворачивает(инвертирует) меняет значение выражения на противоположное.(логическое «НЕ» (NOT): инверсия, отрицание)
true = true
`!`true = false
`!`false = true

на примере с примитивами (3 > 1) - выражение истинно(true) 3 больше 1
`!`(3 > 1) - выражение ложно(false) `(НЕ)`3 больше 1

я когда смотрю код, у себя в голове `!` меняю на `(НЕ)`
if (`!`name.equalsIgnoreCase(targName)) = if (`(НЕ)`name.equalsIgnoreCase(targName))

Метод equalsIgnoreCase() — сравнивает данную строку с другой строкой, игнорируя регистр.

```
if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(targName)) {
                do somtihg ...}
```

читаю как -
если (`(НЕ)` переменная name равна игнорируя регистр переменной targName)
{do somtihg ...}

к примеpу name = "a" , targName = "A"
name.equalsIgnoreCase(targName) - будет true
`!`name.equalsIgnoreCase(targName) - будет false

в итоге если (false) {то делаем что-то...}

Comment: Благодарю за такой развернутый ответ !!! Записываю в тетрадь.

Comment: @oleg23 если ответ устраивает, принимай и поставь галочку

Answer (score 2):

Если `name` отличается от `targName` без учёта регистра.

Если `name` отличается от `targName` не только регистром.